# Why do Blackhat SEO Websites Rank high?

Tags: blackhat

Why does [this](http://www.blackhatworld.com/) website ranks so high in SERP and also has a PR 3. As the name suggests, it promotes black hat seo and the hits on the website are also very high. Why is it that such websites which openly claim to teach such black hat tactics rank so high?

Comment: Why did you expect this not to be the case?

Answer (score 1):

Google won't penalize based on specifically what content you're using, unless it is a link farm, etc. If the hits are high and good SEO, of course it will have a high PR.